# MQTT Websocket Arduino Uno with SIM7600

Tags: websocket, arduino, mqtt, gsm

I'm created a program to connect an Arduino Uno to a MQTT broker.
With the code that you can see below, I can connect to the broker, for testing I use HiveMQ with a plain TCP connection, everything go more or less well.
But for the final broker I'm going to use Websockets secure (wss) and I cant find how to do it.

I read that "I should wrap the client with the websocket", like is made [here](https://github.com/areve/WebSocketStreamClient), the problem is that all the libraries I found  use WiFiClientSecure.h

Do you know any way to do this? Any library or example to use a GSM board to connect using websocket to MQTT?

```
//DEFINITION

#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7600 //have to be before the include
#define Terminal Serial
#define SIM7600RX_PIN 2
#define SIM7600TX_PIN 3
#define SIM7600PWR_PIN 5

//GPRS credentials
const char apn[] = "";
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";

//MQTT
const char* broker = "broker.hivemq.com";
const char* topic = "/testPablo/init";
const char* topiclstWill = "/testPablo/last";
const int mqttPort = 1883;
uint32_t lastReconnectAttempt = 0; 

//INCLUDE LIBRARIES
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

//VARIABLE
SoftwareSerial SIM7600(SIM7600RX_PIN, SIM7600TX_PIN);
TinyGsm modem(SIM7600);
TinyGsmClient client(modem);
PubSubClient mqtt(client);

//Function
void activateSIM7600(){
  Terminal.println("Starting 4G Module...");
  pinMode(SIM7600PWR_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SIM7600PWR_PIN,HIGH);
  delay(15000); //wait SIM7600 to start
  Terminal.println("wait...");
}

bool connectNetwork(){
  Terminal.print("Connecting to network...");
  modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass);
  
  Terminal.print("Waiting for network...");
  if (!modem.waitForNetwork()) {
    Terminal.println(" fail");
    delay(5000);
    return false; 
  }
  Terminal.println(" success");
  if (modem.isNetworkConnected()) {
    Terminal.println("Network connected");
  }  
}

void configureSIM7600(){
  SIM7600.begin(115200);
  modem.init();
  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  Terminal.print("Modem Info: ");
  Terminal.println(modemInfo);
  connectNetwork();
}
void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int len) {
  Terminal.print("Message arrived [");
}
void configureMQTT(){
  // MQTT Broker setup
  mqtt.setServer(broker, 1883);
  mqtt.setCallback(mqttCallback);
}
boolean mqttConnect() {
  Terminal.print("Connecting to ");
  Terminal.print(broker);

  // Connect to MQTT Broker
  boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientTest");
  //authenticate MQTT:
  //boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientName", "mqtt_user", "mqtt_pass");

  if (status == false) {
    Terminal.println(" fail");
    return false;
  }
  Terminal.println(" success");
  mqtt.publish(topic, "GsmClientTest started");
  //mqtt.subscribe(topicLed);
  return mqtt.connected();
}

void setup() {
  Terminal.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  activateSIM7600();
  configureSIM7600();
  configureMQTT();
  Terminal.println("Finish configuration");
}

void loop() {
  if (!mqtt.connected()) {
    Terminal.println("=== MQTT NOT CONNECTED ===");
    uint32_t t = millis(); // Reconnect every 10 seconds
    if (t - lastReconnectAttempt > 10000L) {
      lastReconnectAttempt = t;
      if (mqttConnect()) {
        lastReconnectAttempt = 0;
      }
    }
    delay(100);
    return;
  }

  mqtt.loop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want an Arduino to connect to a broker, in most cases this is done by using ports 1883 or 8883 (secured).

WebSockets are needed if you want to connect to a web client such as a browser and this is done in most cases over ports 8080, 8081 an alike.

Comment: Thanks for answer but no, Mqtt can make a connection over websocket https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-special-mqtt-over-websockets/. I already made it for client in Go, Javascript and other languages.

Comment: Of course, mqtt over websockets is totally there, but what it has to do with your project and code shown above?

Comment: The code above is my first try so I connect without websocket or any security, I saw that worked and now I want to connect to a broker that is already running with websocket and TLS.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the README for the library you've linked to you need to use the `TinyGsmClient` instance instead of the `WifiClientSecure`

Something like:

```
TinyGsmClient client(modem);
WebSocketClient250 wsClient(client, host, port);
WebSocketStreamClient wsStreamClient(wsClient, path);
PubSubClient mqtt(wsStreamClient);
```

This should work for the unsecured version